# c# how to lock object when multiple users reference same object from remote source

Tags: c#, locking

I have the following scenario:

Have a `c# desktop application` on our own infrastructure that is being used by 10 Users.

In a customer server, there is a service that updates (push every 5 min) on our server some remaining Loyalty Points that each employee has.

Then in our app each user can select an employee so they can add some products to his "kind" of shopping cart.

So,lets say employee **John** from the last loyalty points service update stored in our database 500 points.

1. `User X` add 3 products to employee cart that sums 400 points.
2. `User Z`, at same time, he sees also 500 available points and he adds 4 products that sums 200 points.

When `User X` saves the data to our database it will update our local remaining points for that employee so the result will be 500 - 400 = 100.

When `User Z` tries to save we can return to the user a message saying that the remaining points are not enough because we validate before commiting into our database.

The problem comes when by some reason on customer database the value was updated and because we can't pull data on realtime we wont know. So by the time `User X` saves the 400 points maybe in customer database the remaining points are 300.

I have been trying to think on how to assure that users don't add products to our database when the employee in the customer system has less than the sum of products.

> Any recommended solution, architecture? Is the only way would be to request customer to expose us an API so we can pull data on realtime before the user commits any save in our database?

Comment: They way you usually deal with this situation is by maintaining a *row version* [timestamp] of the last update of each record. Example... `User A` and `User B` get the latest Loyalty Points with *row version*, `User A` updates the data with that *row version*, the server allows it. `User B` tries to update with that stale *row version*, the server will throw back a *concurrency error* stating the record has been updated (in essence its out of date). in which case `User B` gets a fresh version of the data (with the now latest *row version*) and then can commit the new changes unimpeded .

Comment: So in this case where User B has an out of date version, does it gets the new version, then points are validated before the user commits to server? or you would make User B to start from scratch the task?  Anyway this can be handled as you said, problem will be doing the customer server remote validation sanity check. So there is no only one source of validation there are two: our employee record (a delayed push from customer service) and customer db (the only source of truth)

Comment: Yes the only thing you can do with this type of concurrency check is get the latest data again, otherwise there is no guarantee after `User B` commits the data will be accurate. 

In regards to who does the validation, its the server. I.e if you use Sql Server, it has a data type called `TimeStamp`, if you try and update a record with the wrong `TimeStamp` it throws a tantrum and returns an error. At that point, `User B` will know they are out of date, and knows they need to refresh the record to get the latest record with the latest `TimeStamp`

Comment: Agree... is the only way to get the latest data again before saving. In the meanwhile I will implement the TimeStamp approach as per your recommendation that makes totally sense.

Comment: "*is the only way to get the latest data again before saving*" i am not sure if this is a question. but yeah.

Comment: Was confirmation :) Thanks Michael.

Comment: The best way is to use a database that is designed for multi users and internally has locking built in.  Do not try to build your own locking in c#,  There is no way that you can 100% in c# guarantee the accuracy of the data if users can bypass your c# application and write directly into the database.  So using stored procedures in the database will work better than in c#.  Also make sure you use a database that supports multi users.  The Microsoft Jet and ACE drivers are not designed for multi users and should be avoided in a multi user application.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, you've not direct access to customers and you can not pull any information. So:

Whenever John tries to do an action that will cause a change at his points, before doing that action, he sends a request to the server to see whether his locker object is locked or not (John synchronizes with the server).

- if the locker object is locked, so he'll get a message that indicates he can not do that action at the time, as server-side users adding products for John's account.
- if the locker object is free, John will lock the locker object in the server which indicates John is changing the point.

If you need to create locks in runtime, you can use [DynaLock](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DynaLock) NuGet package to create and manage locker objects dynamically in real time without being in touch with locking complexities, and of course you can have specific contexts for specific domains.
DynaLock's source code is available at [GitHub](https://github.com/saeedmaghdam/DynaLock)